# In the build folder, why is a concat-file smaller then a "+"file? [Java]

Tags: java, concatenation

As the Title states. Why is the file smaller? I know that "+" invokes a StringBuilder, but I still don't get why this whould lead to more memory usage when the end result is the same.

```
public class ConcatWithPlus {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        String www = "www.";
        String company = "nyhetsbolaget.";
        String country = "se";

        System.out.println(www+company+country);
```

vs

```
public class ConcatWithConcat {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        String www = "www.";
        String company = "nyhetsbolaget.";
        String country = "se";

        System.out.println(www.concat(company).concat(country));
    }
}
```

Comment: what code did you use to create the files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's important to make your question clear and detailled. Show us the two pieces of code you're contrasting (ideally, as full Java files we can compile and compare).

Comment: you gotta be doing something wrong. i tested it and both files had 22 bytes

Comment: Even in the build-folder, where the files have been compiled?

Answer (score 0):

When I try it with javac 1.8.0_152, ConcatWithConcat.class is smaller (568 bytes) than ConcatWithPlus.class (640 bytes). This is to be expected, since the expression `www+company+country` causes the compiler to generate code equivalent to the following:

```
StringBuilder __compilerGeneratedName = new StringBuilder();
__compilerGeneratedName
        .append(www)
        .append(company)
        .append(country)
        .toString();
```

... which is slightly more verbose than using concat, even though the end result is the same.

So why doesn't the compiler generate code equivalent to calling `concat()` if that's smaller? The Java API creators have determined that using `StringBuilder` is more efficient (perhaps because calling `concat` results in creation of intermediate strings).

Comment: Yes, this must be it! Thanks!